# How to call a python script on a new shell window from python code?

Tags: python, bash, terminal

I'm trying to execute 10 python scripts from python code and open each of them in a new shell window.

My code :

```
for i in range(10):
    name_of_file = "myscript"+str(i)+".py"
    cmd = "python " + name_of_file
    os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c " + cmd + "'")
```

But each script file are not executing, I get only the live interpreter of python in the new terminal...

Thank you guys

Comment: I would suggest using the subprocess module, you might have more control over each one...

Comment: In addition to @fedepad I'd like to cite the documentation of [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system): "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `subprocess` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).
In this way, you'll write something like the following:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'bash', '-c']
for i in range(10):
    name_of_file = "myscript"+str(i)+".py"
    your_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd + ['python %s' % (name_of_file)])
    # or if you want to use the "modern" way of formatting string you can write
    # your_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd + ['python {}'.format(name_of_file)])
    ...
```

and you have more control over the processes you start.
If you want to keep using `os.system()`, build your command string first, then pass it to the function. In your case would be:

```
cmd = 'gnome-terminal -x bash -c "python {}"'.format(name_of_file)
os.system(cmd)
```

something along these lines.
Thanks to @anishsane for some suggestions!

Comment: Don't you think, that in the iteration 2, `cmd` will contain something like `['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'bash', '-c', 'python myscript0.py', 'python myscript1.py' ]` instead of `['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'bash', '-c', 'python myscript1.py' ]`...?

Comment: btw, with previous code, you could have used `subprocess.Popen(cmd + ["python {}".format(name_of_file)])`

Comment: @anishsane True, and probably is cleaner this last one that you propose...!!! I like it!

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is to do with the string quoting of the argument to os.system. Try this:

```
os.system("""gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "{}"'""".format(cmd))
```